# How to restore websocket connection with RxJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'd like to try to restore automatically the websocket connection on a website when it aborts. I use RxJS `WebSocketSubject` and `retryWhen`  and `repeatWhen` operators. There are two constraints:

1. try immediately when the connection breaks
2. do not try it again for a period after an unsuccessful re-connection attempt

I wanted to solve my problem with both `throttleTime` and `debounceTime` operators. But the `throttleTime` does not repeat the attempt after the waiting period is over, the `debounceTime` does not try it immediately.

How should I do this? Which is the proper operator/operators?

Comment: It may be relevant to post your code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the expand operator is appropriate here:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html